# How does this transformation work?

Tags: conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

I encountered this expression;

[image]

How do we get $p(x|A)$ from $p_x(x[n]|A)$? I thought we just sum all discrete x[n] values, but in another example there was this one which got me confused.

$p(x[n]|\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta} \text{ for }0 \leq x[n] \leq \theta $

$p(x|\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta^N}$

Comment: What does x[n] represent?

Comment: Observations (n = 0,1,....N-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they're just multiplying the probabilities for $N$ different $x[n]$ values.

$$
\prod_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{\theta} = \frac{1}{\theta^N}
$$

$$
\prod_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{1/2}}\exp\left[\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}(x[n] - A)^2\right] = \frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{N/2}}\exp\left[\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}(x[n] - A)^2\right]
$$

This would make sense if

$$
p(x|A) = \prod_{n=0}^{N-1}p(x[n]|A)
$$

To me that seems like a strange definition of $p(x|A)$, but maybe it makes sense in the context you're looking at?

Comment: Yes, I noticed it was simple multiplication way too late. I'm still not sure why though, but thanks